# How to stop jobs from Spring Cloud Data Flow immediately

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have used Spring Cloud Data Flow to control some batch jobs. In SCDF, after I defined some tasks, they were launched as jobs with running status. When I tried to stop a particular job, It did not stop immediately. I have found that the job was still running until it finished it's current step. 

For example, My job 'ABC' has 2 steps A and B. In SCDF, I stop job 'ABC" when step A is being executed and job 'ABC' is still running until step A is completed and it do not implement step B.

So, Are there any ways to stop a Job immediately from Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Answer (score 1):

From the Spring Cloud Data Flow, the batch job `stop` operation is delegated to the Spring Batch API. This means there is nothing Spring Cloud Data Flow offers to stop a batch job immediately as it needs to be handled by the Spring Batch or the job implementation itself.

When a batch job `stop` request is sent for a Batch Job execution (if it is running), the current step execution is set with the flag `terminateOnly` to `true` which means the step execution is ready to be stopped based on the underlying step execution implementation.

Comment: So my problems would be fixed by configuring in Spring Batch, right? https://github.com/duyetphamm/springbatch . There is a source code of my Spring Batch. Do you have any ideas to deal with my problem?

Comment: Hi, It looks like the default behavior is to wait until the current step completes and check for the `terminateOnly` flag to stop the batch job after the current step.

Comment: So how can I change that default behavior? Do you have any examples?

Comment: This answer is correct. As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59153655/5019386, there is no way to stop execution immediately, you should ask the job to stop, and this what SCDF is doing. As soon as the control goes back to the framework, it will stop the step and its surrounding job.