# how to terminate Job immediately?

Tags: spring-batch

I have tried to stop my job when it is running. But the job do not stop immediately. It is still running and then throws the log:

```
2019-12-03 13:23:48 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.r.s.SimpleJobRepository - Parent JobExecution is stopped, so passing message on to StepExecution
2019-12-03 13:23:48 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.s.ThreadStepInterruptionPolicy - Step interrupted through StepExecution
2019-12-03 13:23:48 [main] INFO  o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered interruption executing step remindStep in job remindEntrustPayment : Job interrupted status detected.
```

How could I terminate Job immediately?

Comment: Probably this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883746/spring-batch-stop-a-job

Comment: No, it's not.  It stop the job but not immediately. the job still run to complete the current step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to force immediate shutdown, especially when the control is in user's code. The `StepInterruptionPolicy` (which defaults to `ThreadStepInterruptionPolicy` that you see in your logs) is checked at chunk boundaries, this is when the control goes back to the framework and stops the job (which is explained in the [Stopping a job](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#stoppingAJob) section).

You can ask to stop a job using `JobOperator#stop` or by setting `StepExecution#setTerminateOnly` in your code when appropriate (using a listener for example).

Comment: I have used Spring Cloud DataFlow to control my spring batch job. Do you have some examples of using JobOperator#stop or StepExecution#setTerminateOnly for my case?

Comment: If you use SCDF to control your jobs, SCDF will send the stop request to the running job when you stop the job from the UI or the CLI. Spring Batch will then stop the job as soon as it gets the control back (at chunk boundaries as explained). So what you are seeing is the normal behaviour: don't expect to hit the stop button and see the jvm stopped immediately. The INFO log messages (`Job interrupted status detected`) show that the job has correctly received the stop signal and is trying to stop gracefully.

Comment: So, after stopping the job, it still finish the current step and just do not implement next steps( when it gets the control back)? Is that what you mean?

Comment: I may not expect to stop the jvm. What I am looking for is some ways to stop (or changes the flow, or detect immediately request from SCDF) when my Spring Batch receives stopping request from SCDF. For example, my ItemWritter can send 1 2 3 4 ...n  mails. But I use SCDF to stop job while the 4th mail is sent, the next after 5th mail will not be sent.

Comment: It depends on your chunk size. In your example, if chunkSize=5 , then the step will check if it has been asked to stop after processing items [1,2,3,4,5] and not after the 4th item. The idea of chunk processing is that each chunk is processed as a unit in a transaction. The `StepInterruptionPolicy` is checked at chunk-boundaries means before/after each chunk (transaction) and not with-in the chunk after each item.

Comment: That 's my issue. Thanks you

Comment: How to handle my problem if using tasklet approach? Are there anyway to configure chunk size in tasklet?